# Writing to Password Protected .XLSX file

Tags: python, openpyxl

Is it possible to open and write to a password protected .XLSX file using Openpyxl?

Possibly another argument added to the load_workbook() method?

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'Test.xlsx')
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Can I open password-protected excel files or not?](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/193/can-i-open-password-protected-excel-files) and [Open password protected workbook](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/26/open-password-protected-workbook), *opening password-protected excel files with openpyxl is not supported*.